# group by date in linq

Tags: linq-to-sql

I've a table with datetime null field in sql server. I'm trying to group the results based on the year in that field. But, when I wrote linq query, I didn't get intellisense for Year when I type that field. It only shows HasValue and Value. I think because it is converted nullable type. How do I do the grouping in this case?

Comment: can you show us the query? At a guess I'd say `DateTimeField.Value.Year`

Comment: @Matt Ellen Great. Your guess is absolutely right. Thanks a lot my friend. I think I was just a step away.

Comment: I don't know how to mark Matt's comment as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should group on the Year of the value of the `Nullable<DateTime>` so

```
group obj by obj.DateTimeField.Value.Year into g
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, keep in mind accessing `.Value` property of your [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) type may throw `InvalidOperationException` when there's no value (as in - field is `NULL` in database).

In which case you can either filter out null values:

```
var filteredGroups = rows.Where(row => row.DateTimeField.HasValue)
                         .GroupBy(row => row.DateTimeField.Value.Year);
```

...or return null values aswell; say under some dummy key:

```
var nullValuesPresent = rows.GroupBy(row => row.DateTimeField.HasValue 
    ? row.DateTimeField.Value.Year : -1);
```

...which in the example above, will be grouped under `-1` key (or whatever value you choose to represent non-existing year scenario).